# How to keep one toggle open by default javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering is it possible to keep one toggle open on page load by default, i have been tearing my hair out on this one.
any help will be appreciated.

Its the your account toggle i am trying to keep open!

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#account").show("slow").siblings().hide("slow");
    $('a#francc').click(function () {
        var divname = this.name;
        $("#" + aname).show("slow").siblings().hide("slow");
    });
});
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
    <a  id="order" class="header" href="#" onclick="toggleVisibility('Order');"><h3 id="orderr">Orders</h3></a>
    <div id="Order" style="display: none;">  </div>
              
    <a id="restt" class ="header"href="#" onclick="toggleVisibility('Rest');"><h3>Your Restaurants</h3></a>
    <div id="Rest" style="display: none;"><div>
              
    <!-- your account -->
    <a id="francc" name="account" class ="header" href="#" onclick="toggleVisibility('Franc');"><h3>Your Account</h3></a>
    <div id="Franc" style="display: none;">
        <div>
            <ul class="tabs">
                <li id="order" class="Red"><a href="Franchise-account-orders.php">Franchise Manager</a></li>
                <li id="order" class="Blue" ><a href="admin_panel.php">Pending</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is `aname` coming from?

Comment: same question i asked my lecturer. He said <a href tag and the name="" attribute

Comment: No that isn't in the code. There's a lot wrong in the code - you have HTML onclick and jQuery for example.

Comment: new to all this, just trial and error really. There is a lot more going on with the code then just this, so them attributes you've mentioned are to do with my toggle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, just remove that sibling from the selection. There's a lot wrong with your HTML too. I've removed the onclicks, and you had an opening div tag where a closed one should have been.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    // set up the click event
    $('.sidebar > a').on('click', function(){
      $(this).next('div').show("slow").siblings('div:not(#Franc)').hide("slow");
    });
    // trigger orders which has id francc, not orders
    $('#francc').trigger('click');
    // or perhaps you mean this, but it's slower // $('a[name="account"]').trigger('click');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sidebar">
    <a  id="order" class="header" href="#"><h3 id="orderr">Orders</h3></a>
    <div id="Order" style="display: none;"> orders dropdown </div>
              
    <a id="restt" class ="header" href="#"><h3>Your Restaurants</h3></a>
    <div id="Rest" style="display: none;">Your Restaurants dropdown</div>
              
    <!-- your account -->
    <a id="francc" name="account" class ="header" href="#"><h3>Your Account</h3></a>
    <div id="Franc" style="display: none;">
        <div>
            <ul class="tabs">
                <li id="order" class="Red"><a href="Franchise-account-orders.php">Franchise Manager</a></li>
                <li id="order" class="Blue" ><a href="admin_panel.php">Pending</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you. but doesn't work, i think its down to the aname as you said before, trying to figure another way to do it

Comment: I don't see why you have aname. I'm updating the answer to what it should probably be

Comment: i worked out that div name is meant to be divs=['franc'], as this variable is stated in my toggle, still trying to get my head around it

Comment: ohhhh thank you just seen the update. i will see if it works

Answer (score 0):

this will work, http://fiddle.jshell.net/9oo1jrr9/

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Rest").show().siblings('div').hide();
});
function toggleVisibility(ctrlThis){
    $("#" + ctrlThis).first('div').show("slow").siblings('div').hide();
}
</script>
<div class="sidebar">
 <a  id="order" class="header" href="#" onclick="toggleVisibility('Order');"><h3 id="orderr">Orders</h3></a>
 <div id="Order" style="display: none;">
    <div>
            <ul class="tabs">
                <li id="order" class="Red">Order 1</li>
                <li id="order" class="Blue" >Order 2</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
 </div>
 <a id="restt" class ="header" href="#" onclick="toggleVisibility('Rest');"><h3>Your Restaurants</h3></a>
 <div id="Rest" style="display: none;">
     <div>
            <ul class="tabs">
                <li id="order" class="Red">Restaurants 1</li>
                <li id="order" class="Blue" >Restaurants 2</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
 </div>
 <a id="francc" name="account" class ="header" href="#" onclick="toggleVisibility('Franc');"><h3>Your Account</h3></a>
 <div id="Franc" style="display: none;">
        <div>
            <ul class="tabs">
                <li id="order" class="Red"><a href="Franchise-account-orders.php">Franchise Manager</a></li>
                <li id="order" class="Blue" ><a href="admin_panel.php">Pending</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```